# Sqoop job intelligence

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

In a scenario, if there is one single sqoop job which we use to import 250 rows of data once and 250 rows of data again, so is there any way of knowing which execution of the sqoop job imported which data?

Answer (score 0):

Every `sqoop job` will create some part-m files, the number of the files depends 
 on mappers. So you can compare the creation time of these files.

Otherwise, If you know for the desired `sqoop job` the ID (e.g **JOB ID**: 
 1234567891234_4201)  you can go to find the `log_file` of JOB.

**Import Data through Hue**

Look into the file and try to find the  `Sqoop command arguments:` section.
 You will see the **sqoop command** which was executed by you.

**Import Data through Sqoop command line**

Look into the file and try to find the `Processing file`  section. 
  You will see the name of the part-m file which was created by the searching **JOB 
  ID** .